# How to clear Rails class cache for a specific class (ActiveRecord Model)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

When I type `Rails.cache.clear` ALL the cache made by Rails is cleared. But in my production environment, I set in `config/environments/production.rb` the configuration `config.cache_classes = true`.
But, sometimes, I need to clear cache of a specific class (in my case, a specific ActiveRecord model), not all.

How do I clear the Rails cache made for a specific ActiveRecord Model?

Comment: `cache_classes` defined if your applications source code is reloaded on each request. This has nothing to data caching. Can you please explain which cache exactly you want to clear (data, query, code) and will you need to do that?

Comment: @spickermann I want to clear the cache of code (Ruby code) of classes. In my case, clear the cache of code of a specific ActiveRecord Model (because clear ALL cache make a huge impact on page load and request time of application).

Comment: @PedroFurtado. Wow. Rails.cache.clear not related to code reloading. It does not refresh code. So, you want something like `load "#{Rails.root}/app/models/category.rb"`. But beware that doing this may cause errors in production environment. If You use several rails instances, that code would reload the class only on one!

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.cache.delete("/posts") # for model Post
Rails.cache.delete("/posts/id") # for single post
```

For clear [all database query](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-clear_query_cache):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.clear
```

> One reason you may wish to call this method explicitly is between queries that ask the database to randomize results. Otherwise the cache would see the same SQL query and repeatedly return the same result each time, silently undermining the randomness you were expecting.

Comment: your two lines are the same